# Using Launchy to search Gmail

Tags: gmail

I use the Weby extension for Launchy to do custom searches. I should be able to search Gmail like this

[image: screenshot]

using this search definition

```
Mail   http://mail.google.com/a/caudillweb.com/#search/%1
```

[image]

but the forward slash following `#search` gets rewritten to a backslash, so the URL that is sent to the browser is

```
 http://mail.google.com/a/caudillweb.com/#search\foo@caudillweb.com
```

Gmail doesn't like the backslash, so it considers the URL invalid and redirects to `#inbox`.

Any ideas how I can stop Launchy (or Weby) from reversing that forward slash?

Comment: Looks like this has been identified as a bug:
http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2987199&group_id=132975&atid=725839

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I'm on a different version of Launchy/Weby, but when I configured mine I used the following settings and they worked great:

```
Name: mail
URL: https://mail.google.com/mail/
Query: #search/%s
```

Maybe the use of `%1` threw it off?

Comment: I think maybe you're using an older version? Mine is 2.5, and as you can see in the screenshot that I just added, there's only a `Name` column and a `URL` column.

Comment: Ah, correct.  I'm still on 2.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem using Launchy 2.5.0 by replacing the `#` with `%23`.

For instance, when searching contacts, this URL string for searching Google contacts passed through Launchy without exhibiting the bug:

```
http://mail.google.com/mail/%23contacts/search/%1
```

Perhaps this can help with your example above.

That said, I just use this search term instead for Gmail:

```
http://mail.google.com/mail/?search=query&view=tl&q=%1
```

This does not exhibit the bug nor have the `%23` hack.