# How to search Google Contacts directly from Launchy (or as a browser custom search engine)?

Tags: google-contacts

I am trying to figure out if there is a Google URL where I can pass in my search value to go straight to the Google Contacts search results page.  I want to do this in Launchy, but the answer would also help with Custom Search Engines from within the major browsers.

For example, in Gmail, I can use the following URL:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#search/%1
```

where `%1` is my search string.

I would like to do something similar with Google Contacts, but I cannot find the correct URL.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that thru Launchy unless Launchy can provide a way to authenticate you. Have you been able to use that example URL anywhere but in your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current url is `https://contacts.google.com/search/%s`.

I bookmarked it in Firefox, gave it a keyword `cont` and now I can search my contacts from the location bar like this: `cont pavel` (redirects to `https://contacts.google.com/search/pavel`)

Comment: Yep, this one works

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution to this, using what Jody suggested above as a basis.

The "#" appears to be what prevents the search URL from working. Replacing it with a %23 solved the trick. Thus, use Weby to specify the following string:

http://mail.google.com/mail/%23contacts/search/%1

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid the Gmail interface (which is rather heavy for just checking contacts), you can do this through the Google Contacts interface.

The search result page would look like this:

`https://www.google.com/contacts/#contacts/search/%s` (with %s your search string)

I don't know about Launchy, but in Chrome a custom search engine set up with that string would do it. Here's an example:

[image: Contact search in Chrome]
(the URL does not fit in the screen width, but it's exactly as the one above)

Comment: This doesn't appear to work now.  I suspect the Google Contacts redesign last year may have broken it.

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible with the following URL, assuming you're already logged into Gmail:

```
http://mail.google.com/mail/#contacts/search/%1
```

However, there seems to be a bug in the current distribution of Launchy (2.5.0) that prevents it. See here:

- [Using Launchy to search Gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5506/using-launchy-to-search-gmail)
- http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2987199&group_id=132975&atid=725839

Claims to be fixed in 2.5.1.  Download 2.6beta release from launchy.net

Comment: Jody-  Your link for "Using Launchy to search Gmail" is broken.  Do you have another link?

Comment: it's not broken for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much a project you're interested in, but Google does provide API access to your data via API (like [contacts](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/)) with authentication handled by OAuth.  Putting together a little perl script to glue stuff together with something like [Mojo::UserAgent](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/UserAgent) would be a fun little project.